# Trouble Implementing nested loops into a recursive solution

Tags: c++, recursion

**Non-Recursive Code**

Here is the code I am trying to convert into a recursive solution.

```
int main()
{
    int number[3];
    for (number[0]=0; number[0] <= 9; number[0]++) 
    {   
        for (number[1]=0; number[1] <= 4; number[1]++)
        {
            for (number[2]=0; number[2] <= 9; number[2]++)
            {
                std::cout << number[0] << number[1] << number[2] << std::endl; 
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Press any key to continue";
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code can be found here http://pastebin.com/f20X3gT3.

**Recursive Attempt**

Here is my failed attempt at replicating the above algorithm into a recursive solution.  It compiles without any errors but it does not give the same results as the above Non-Recursive solution does.

```
#include <iostream>

const int NumberLength = 3;
int number[3];
int element;

void generateFormula(const int Length) {
    if(Length == 0) {
        for (int n = 0; n <= NumberLength; ++n) {
            std::cout << number[n];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return; 
    }
    if(element%2==0) {
        for(number[element]=0; number[element] <= 9; number[element]++);
            generateFormula(Length-1);
    }
    else {
        for(number[element]=0; number[element] <= 4; number[element]++);
            generateFormula(Length-1);
    }
    element++;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= NumberLength; ++i)
        generateFormula(i);

    std::cout << "Press any key to continue";
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0000 
10000
10501
10500
```

Comment: Nested loops != Recursive function calls.

Comment: You have three nested loops, one would expect some kind of triply nested recursive call in your recursive solution, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your function quite a bit.  Using [`std::setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) you don't need to have three different variables.You can change the iterative approach to

```
void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 950; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << setfill('0') << i << "\n";
        if (((i+1) % 50) == 0)
            i += 50;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c81a70a26b27af8)</kbd>

And the recursive approach would become:

```
void print(int i)
{

    cout << setw(3) << setfill('0') << i << "\n";
    if (i == 949)
        return;
    if (((i+1) % 50) == 0)
        i += 50;
    print(++i);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/865309d3c7276821)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you change your function a little bit, you'll be able to see how it can be transformed to a recursive function.

```
// Drive it using externally supplied data.
void generateFormula1(int number[], int loopCounter[])
{
   for (; number[0] <= loopCounter[0]; number[0]++) 
   {   
      for (; number[1] <= loopCounter[1]; number[1]++)
      {
         for (; number[2] <= loopCounter[2]; number[2]++)
         {
            std::cout << number[0] << number[1] << number[2] << std::endl; 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, it is a bit easier to transform it to a recursive function.

```
void generateFormula2(int number[], int loopCounter[], int nestingLevel)
{
   // The terminating condition of the recursive function.
   if ( nestingLevel == 3 )
   {
      std::cout << number[0] << number[1] << number[2] << std::endl; 
      return;
   }

   for (; number[nestingLevel] <= loopCounter[nestingLevel]; number[nestingLevel]++) 
   {
      generateFormula2(number, loopCounter, nestingLevel+1);
   }
}
```

Test it using:

```
int main()
{
   int loopCounter[3] = {9, 4, 9};

   int number1[3] = {0};
   generateFormula1(number1, loopCounter);

   int number2[3] = {0};
   generateFormula2(number2, loopCounter, 0);

   return 0;
}
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/JH76sa.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(int x, int y, int z){
    std::cout << '(' << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")\n";
    ++x;
    if(x == 10){
        x = 0;
        ++y;
        if(y == 10){
            y = 0;
            ++z;
            if(z == 10)
                return;
        }
    }
    print(x, y, z);
}

auto main() -> int{
    print(0, 0, 0);
}
```

This will print out `(0, 0, 0)` through to `(9, 9, 9)`

You can replace `x`, `y` and `z` with whatever you like and modify the parameters of the `if` statements to get the results you want. You could also generalize the function to get a limit for each parameter:

```
template<int XLim, int YLim, int ZLim>
void print(int x, int y, int z){
    std::cout << '(' << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")\n";
    if(z >= ZLim && y >= YLim && z >= ZLim) return;

    ++x;
    if(x == 10){
        x = 0;
        ++y;
        if(y == 10){
            y = 0;
            ++z;
            if(z == 10) return;
        }
    }
    print<XLim, YLim, ZLim>(x, y, z);
}

auto main() -> int{
    print<9, 4, 9>(0, 0, 0);
}
```